# how to append after load jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I already have some data in the elements i just want to load and append something more,
I want to load and append on each element that has the atribute data-load.
I was doing this but isn't working. Can someone help me on this, thanks.

```
$(function(){
    $("[data-load]").each(function(index){
        var $tmp = $('<div>');
        var valueData = $(this).data("load")
        $tmp.load(valueData);
        $(this).append($tmp.html());
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`load()` is a shortcut convenience method for `$.ajax()`.

AJAX is asynchronous so the http request won't have completed at the time when you are trying to get the returned html from inside `$tmp`

You need to use the complete callback of `load()` to do anything within the returned result

To continue using load() method Try:

```
 $("[data-load]").each(function (index) {
     var $tmp = $('<div>'),
         $el = $(this);
     var valueData = $(this).data("load")
     $tmp.load(valueData, function () {
         /* the ajax has completed here */
         $el.append($tmp.html());
     });

 });
```

Another shortcut method of `$.ajax` is `$.get` which I think would make this code more readable and a little shorter by not needing to create a temporary storage element

```
 $("[data-load]").each(function (index) {
     var $el = $(this);
     $.get($el.data("load"), function(response){
         $el.append(response);
     });    

 });
```

Both solutions assume that `data-load` attribute is a valid url that returns the html expected.

Comment: most important part of ajax is understanding that it takes time to get the data from the server and other code doesn't wait for this to happen =>asynchronous